# What is the difference between python and arduino programming?

Tags: python

I am a Python programmer and want to learn Arduino programming so want to know what are the main differences between Python and Arduino C++ programming?

Is Arduino C++ more complex than Python programming?
Are there any similarities that will help me?
Are there any formatting  restrictions like in Python?
Etc...

According to [this page(printing hello)](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/HelloWorld), Aurdino programming looks easy to me.

Comment: `What is the difference between python and arduino programming?` -- **Everything**.

Comment: Heh.  As usual, @Majenko is correct.  This is like asking what the difference is between FORTRAN and COBOL.  From this question it sounds like you don't really know either Python nor C++

Comment: @SDsolar I know python but not C++

Comment: @ShopiMacros - If you know one language learning a second is easier than learning a first.  Start with small examples and work up.

Comment: @CodeGorilla , Got It

Comment: I agree with the Gorilla.  If you really want to have fun, look at this link.  It shows how to say "Hello, World" in 28 different languages..  It is interesting to see the similarities and differences.  Both Python and C++ are in there.   https://excelwithbusiness.com/blog/say-hello-world-in-28-different-programming-languages/

Comment: Python works great on everything except Arduino, where you use C++.  It is amazingly easy to use Arduinos.   Start with the built-in examples, like Blink.  Here is an article on that subject:  https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples

Comment: @SDsolar Its interesting alot.

Comment: Have fun with it!   The best thing about programming is that you have the freedom to control everything.  The worst thing about programming is that you have to control everything.  That was the joke when I was in CS school.

Comment: btw, please edit your question here and make it very clear that you are a Python programmer and want to know how hard of a leap it might be to use C++ on Arduino.  You have said plenty in the comments that, if included in the question, might even get the hold released.

Comment: @SDsolar is there anything missing now?

Comment: Your edit only makes this question worse.  Fundamentally, it does not fit here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arduino uses a language that is derived from Processing, which looks like C++.

Python is a different language, although both have similarities (both Object Oriented for example).

What is 'complex' depends on what your background is. C++ is in general more complex than Arduino, but most people using Arduino program in C++, so most examples can be found in C++, which makes support from other users easier.

If you are new to programming, I suggest using the 'standard' Arduino IDE.

To be complete, Arduino is not a programming language, it is a platform. In general, every language can be used to write Arduino code, but only a few have compilers for creating Arduino (machine) code.

Comment: Arduino uses the gcc compiler which is 100% 'c++'. The 'c++' includes automatically 'c' (although some would say that is is no longer pure 'c' because there are very tiny differences for example with keywords that are needed in 'c++'). On top of the 'c++' the Arduino platform has put an extra sauce. That extra layer can be a blessing or a curse or just confusing. In my opinion it is a little of each of those three things. Newer Arduino boards have faster processors and more memory, so there is no more holding back to use 'c++' to the full.

Comment: @Jot> well, there are [C constructs that do not exist in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1201840/3212865). C++ doesn't include C, only a subset of it.

Comment: It sure is easy to get sidetracked by discussions about languages.  For Arduino I say just do what @Michael says and use the Arduino IDE (and the built-in examples) to get into the mindset.

Comment: I tried to make my answer suitable to the one who asked ... Jot is right mostly that C++/C and the Arduino 'language'  are similar, but from a start point of view, it's best to start simple (which is the Arduino IDE).

Comment: Understood.  I like your answer so upvoted.  It was a challenge to answer it as asked.  @Chris improved the body but I still think the title is not compelling enough for people to find this one after it is not new and goes inactive.

Comment: @SDSolar Thanks ... and also it's partly opinion-based (what is complex or not). E.g. for me electronics is more complex than programming, since I have more experience in the latter. Some people like OO, others prefer non-OO etc.